# Comparing binary cross entropy loss tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I created binary_cross_entropy_loss according to formula below:

```
import numpy as np

def binary_cross_entropy_loss(y_hat: np.ndarray, y_true: np.ndarray) -> float:
    y_hat = np.clip(y_hat, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)

    return -(y_true * np.log(y_hat) + (1 -y_true) * np.log(1 - y_hat)).mean()
```

However when I tried to compare TensorFlow BinaryCrossentropy with `from_logits=False` I saw that results are different but with `from_logits=True` are nearly identical.

My questions are:

- Where does this difference come from?
- How to achieve quite close results with from_logits=False?
- Which formula with from_logits=False is better and why?

Code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true: np.ndarray = np.float32([0, 1, 0, 0])
y_pred: np.ndarray = np.float32([-18.6, 0.51, 2.94, -12.8])


print("numpy, from_logits=False: ", binary_cross_entropy_loss(y_pred, y_true))
print("tensorflow, from_logits=False: ", tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)(y_true, y_pred).numpy())


def sigmoid(x: np.array) -> np.ndarray:
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

print("numpy, from_logits=True: ", binary_cross_entropy_loss(sigmoid(y_pred), y_true))
print("tensorflow, from_logits=True: ", tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
```

```sh
numpy, from_logits=False:  4.1539326
tensorflow, from_logits=False:  4.0016456
numpy, from_logits=True:  0.86545783
tensorflow, from_logits=True:  0.865458
```